# How to display the same code, when you are logged in on different pages in jsp?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

everyone.

I just start learning Spring+Bootstrap and I create a web app, where I have an Admin CP section... I created the login functions, and display some content when you have logged in and a Warning message when you are not logged in.

So my problem is the use of  tags.

I have the following structure of my code.

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${mode == 'ADMINCP' }">

   <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${loggedIn eq true }">
    <!-- Start NavBar Code -->          
 </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<!-- Start Code to diplay warning message when you are not logged in -->
</c:otherwise>
</choose>

</c:when>
</choose>
```

I used that first c:when tag () , because if I don't when I'm not logged in that warning message will shop up everywhere in my pages even those which you don't need to be logged in to see them.

And the question is.
How can I add different c:when tags inside on this one

```
 <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${loggedIn eq true }">
```

after my Navbar code, which will represent different pages.

The final Structure will be like this.

```
  <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${mode == 'ADMINCP' }">

       <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${loggedIn eq true }">
        <!-- Start NavBar Code -->  


  <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${mode == 'ANOTHER PAGE' }">

        </c:when>

<c:when test="${mode == 'ANOTHER PAGE' }">

        </c:when>
</choose>


     </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <!-- Start Code to diplay warning message when you are not logged in -->
    </c:otherwise>
    </choose>

    </c:when>
</choose>
```

And on the end to have in all my admin cp pages the nav bar, and their content to be displayed only if the user is logged in.

P.S I already try this code and for some reason is not working.

Thanks, everyone in advance.

Comment: A possible solution for this is Thymeleaf, see Thymeleaf page layout section http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

Comment: Can you please provide value for all the variables that are being used in conditions?